# Jquery selecting last tr doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to select the last tr, so the animation appears only for it. But in whatever way I try to select it, every time all tr are getting selected.
Here is my code:

HTML

```
<tbody>
  <tr class="">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>w w</td>
    <td>Demokratska</td>
    <td>undefined</td>
    <td><a href="#" class="uredi" data-id="1">Uredi</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="">
    <td>2</td>
    <td>w w</td>
    <td>Demokratska</td>
    <td>undefined</td>
    <td><a href="#" class="uredi" data-id="2">Uredi</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="">
    <td>3</td>
    <td>w w</td>
    <td>Demokratska</td>
    <td>undefined</td>
    <td><a href="#" class="uredi" data-id="3">Uredi</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="">
    <td>4</td>
    <td>w w</td>
```

Jquery UI

```
$(".table tbody tr:last").addClass("dodajZapis", 500).delay(1000);

$(".table tr:last").removeClass("dodajZapis", 500);
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the . from `.table` unless your tables class is actually table.  Your selector should be `"table tbody tr:last"`.

Comment: There are other tables, so I added a class to this one, hence the .table.

Comment: Could you include the complete table element so we can see what's going on?

Comment: The plunker works fine for me, the last row is red for a bit then fades out.  Is it not working for you?

Comment: The identical code is not working. All tr are getting selected: http://prntscr.com/b4dg69

Comment: Unfortunately there's not too much more I can do to help without seeing more of the code.  Everything you've posted here works fine!

Answer (score 0):

Seems ok for me:

```
  <table class="table">
    <tbody>
      <tr class="">
        <td>1</td>
        <td>w w</td>
        <td>Demokratska</td>
        <td>undefined</td>
        <td><a href="#" class="uredi" data-id="1">Uredi</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="">
        <td>2</td>
        <td>w w</td>
        <td>Demokratska</td>
        <td>undefined</td>
        <td><a href="#" class="uredi" data-id="2">Uredi</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="">
        <td>3</td>
        <td>w w</td>
        <td>Demokratska</td>
        <td>undefined</td>
        <td><a href="#" class="uredi" data-id="3">Uredi</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="">
        <td>4</td>
        <td>w w</td>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <script>
    $(".table tbody tr:last").addClass("dodajZapis", 500).delay(1000);

    $(".table tr:last").removeClass("dodajZapis", 500);
  </script>
```

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/9G9C6AyUZTLN6mOzPHbe?p=preview

Comment: That's odd. Could ther be an issue with my browser? I'm using Chrome...
The table rows are also added dynamically, with js, Could this be an issue?

Comment: humm, so you need to call these two lines after adding your rows, i.e., after your ajax success callback or somewhere else.

Comment: Those lines are called after the lines are added. So that shouldn't be the issue

Answer (score 0):

I had the Jquery in a for loop(the one that prints the tr) which applied the animation to every tr... Now it works fine